# Webpack 4 + jQuery + jQuery Migrate

Tags: webpack

I'm facing an issue while moving from Webpack v3 to v4, my app is quite big and has an old part that relies on jQuery + jQuery Migrate, in webpack 3 it was working all OK as follows:

1. jQuery + jQuery Migrate are imported in a common.js entry file.
2. In all other modules (in each entry) we only import jQuery

In v4 I've been playing with configurations and nothing works for me, basically what happens is that in any other entry file I get an error **(`$(...).live is not a function` or `$.browser is undefined`)** because migrate is not loaded in this case, I do not want to import migrate in all modules where I import jQuery, I just need that jQuery + jQuery Migrate are loaded together always, ideas? What should be the configuration for splitChunks?